# Rails Active Record iteration and printing results returning unnormal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to Print a Active Record result to my view ... normally I do someting like that:

```
<% if channelList.present? %>
<% channelList.each do |channel| %>
    <li>
      <div class="bp-movies-list-movie">
        <div class="bp-channel-list-image">
          <img src="<%= channel.channelimage %>"/>
```

But If I do this I got this error:

```
undefined method `channelimage' for #<Channel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f2189489bd8>
```

My channelList object looks like this:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Channel id: 1, channelname: "Smart", created_at: "2016-04-24 13:47:11", updated_at: "2016-05-05 07:40:21", channeldescription: "Coole Smarts", channelprice: 1.0, currency: "€", free: false, locked: true, channelimage: "Screenshot_2016.04.09_16h24m03s_007_.png", knowledgeprovider_id: 1>, #<Channel id: 2, channelname: "Zimmer", created_at: "2016-05-04 21:20:59", updated_at: "2016-05-04 21:20:59", channeldescription: "asdad", channelprice: 1.0, currency: "€", free: false, locked: false, channelimage: "_SEE7468.jpg", knowledgeprovider_id: 1>]>, #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Channel id: 5, channelname: "Emies erster Channel", created_at: "2016-05-05 08:57:56", updated_at: "2016-05-05 08:57:56", channeldescription: "asdasd", channelprice: 1.0, currency: "€", free: false, locked: false, channelimage: "2015-12-26_12.20.07.jpg", knowledgeprovider_id: 3>]>]
```

Where is my Problem?

Update:

Fetching data:

```
@channelList = Array.new

@knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider

@knowledgeproviderList.each do |kp|
  @c = Channel.where("knowledgeprovider_id = ?", kp.id)
  puts @c.inspect
  @channelList.push @c
end
```

Comment: You have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` inside an array.   So the `.each` iterates over the array, which has the relation as it's first element, so you're trying to call `channel_image` on the relation hence the error.  So don't put the relation in an array when you define `chanellList`

Comment: can you post your code to see how you are getting `channelList` ?

Comment: I've added my controller code above

Comment: you have one channel per knowledgeprovider_id ?

Comment: yes. Each channel is only related to one knowledgeprovider

Comment: Why is `@user.knowledgeprovider` returning an array? it looks like a single value to me.

Comment: A user can have several knowledgeprovider

Comment: then you can see my answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instread of this loop, and doing multiple sql queries, adding the results to an array...

```
@channelList = Array.new

@knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider

@knowledgeproviderList.each do |kp|
  @c = Channel.where("knowledgeprovider_id = ?", kp.id)
  puts @c.inspect
  @channelList.push @c
end
```

Map the ids and do one query

```
@knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider
@channelList = Channel.where(knowledgeprovider_id: @knowledgeproviderList.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Use `@knowledgeproviderList.pluck(:id)` instead of a `.map(&:id)`. It will be more efficient, especially if `@knowledgeproviderList` is large.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed Thank you!

Comment: whats the difference between pluck and map?

Comment: Better yet, just do `@channelList = Channel.where(knowledgeprovider_id: @user.knowledge_provider_ids)`. It might be best to define a `user` `has_many :channels` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `channelList` appears to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` nested in an array.

I'd be willing to bet changing `<% channelList.each do |channel| %>` to `<% channelList.first.each do |channel| %>` solves this specific error.

If you include your controller code it may shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your controller code to 
if one channel per knowledgeprovider_id

```
@channelList = Array.new

@knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider

@knowledgeproviderList.each do |kp|
  @c = Channel.where("knowledgeprovider_id = ?", kp.id).first
  puts @c.inspect
  @channelList.push @c
end
```

If more than one channel possible than change view code like:

```
<% if channelList.present? %>
<% channelList.each do |channels| %>
   <% channels.each do |channel| %>
    <li>
      <div class="bp-movies-list-movie">
        <div class="bp-channel-list-image">
          <img src="<%= channel.channelimage %>"/>
```